# Delphi protect inherited Destrutor from exception

Tags: delphi

I have a TMyFileStream that extend TFileStream.

```
type
   TMyFileStream = class(TFileStream)
```

In TMyFileStream.Destroy i have some procedure used for logging server downloads. The file stream is passed in the response stream, when the client close connection with server or terminate download of the response the object is destroyed and the destructor log information like bytes send/file size.

This procedure that could raise exception first of call parent decostructor. I want protect the parent destructor from child exception.

basic example

```
destructor TMyFileStream.Destroy;
begin
   MyExceptionMethod();

   inherited;
end;
```

First solution i found is call the inherited destructor first of all

```
destructor TMyFileStream.Destroy;
begin
   inherited;

   MyExceptionMethod();
end;
```

another solution is catch and ignore exception

```
destructor TMyFileStream.Destroy;
begin
   try
      MyExceptionMethod();
   except
      // nothing
   end;

   inherited;
end;
```

another solution is catch and call the inherited destructor in finally

```
destructor TMyFileStream.Destroy;
begin
   try
      try
         MyExceptionMethod();
      except
         // nothing
      end;
   finally
      inherited;
   end;
end;
```

what is the right way?

Comment: Not clear why are you doing it. Do you want to catch exceptions raised in constructor?

Comment: @user246408 no i have some procedure in decostructor 
that could raise exception first of call parent decostructor

Comment: Please be more specific on your real problem. Doing descendant's finalization before ancestor's is a stereotypical way to finalize, swapping these operations is likely an error.

Comment: Fix your destructor so that it doesn't raise an exception, and you won't have this problem.

Comment: @KenWhite destructor perform some logging features and can raise exception sometimes... the basic solution is catch exception

Comment: No, the basic solution is not to do logging in the destructor. The destructor should free any resources and **destroy the object**. It shouldn't be doing all kinds of other things.

Comment: @KenWhite this technique is used for logging server downloads. The file stream is passed in the response stream, when the client close connection with server or terminate download of the response the object is destroyed and the destructor log information like byte sends/file size. I know it is not the best way...

Comment: No. You've got it all horribly wrong. The contract of a destructor is that it does not raise. End. Of. Story.

Comment: You're doing it wrong. The destructor should be doing exactly what I described - nothing more. It's not only not the best way, it's the totally wrong way.

Comment: ok, guys... thank you. I decided to rewrite my code in a new way...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

An alternative would be to override `BeforeDestruction`, there `inherited` is not related to the actual de-allocation of the instance's memory.

Comment: If `BeforeDestruction()` raises an exception, `Destroy()` exits, and an  overridden `Destroy()` will not be able to run its code or call `inherited`! `BeforeDestruction()` is not protected from exceptions.

Comment: Indeed, all the same issues apply with BeforeDestruction.

Comment: Not all the issues, specifically the placement of inherited up front will not cause access violations because the actual deallocation took place like in Destroy.